# How to get JasperReport exported to excel format generated using Java code to base64 encoded string and decode it

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am able to generate Jasper report file and the export it to excel file while saving it to disk (It works as expected with proper display of data). If Instead of a file as output, if I use ByteArrayOutputStream as Output, I get a byte array. If I encode the stream into Base64 and further decode it and save the string in an xlsx file, it shows corrupted data.

```
{
//some code....
ReportService reportService = new ReportService();
JasperPrint jp = rawreport.getReport();
data = reportService.getReportXlsx(jp);//function defined below
BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String encckycstr = base64Encoder.encodeBuffer(data);
//If I put encckycstr into a new text file and save it has xlsx
String destinationPath = "E:\\Destination\\data.xls";
//decode Base64 String to image
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath); 
byte[] bytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encckycstr);
fos.write(bytes);
fos.close();
//when I open data.xls, it doesnt open in excel or openoffice calc.
//some code.....

}

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
import com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRXlsxExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.DefaultFormatFactory;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.DurationNumberFormat;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRGenericPrintElementParameterFactory.Parameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration;

public byte[] getReportXlsx(final JasperPrint jp) throws JRException, 
IOException {
    JRXlsxExporter xlsxExporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
    final byte[] rawBytes;

    //for byte array export
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream xlsReport = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
        jp.setProperty(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, "true");
        xlsxExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jp));
        xlsxExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(xlsReport));
        SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration xlsxreportConfig = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
        xlsxreportConfig.setSheetNames(new String[] { "Some Report" });
        xlsxreportConfig.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
        xlsxreportConfig.setForcePageBreaks(false);
        xlsxreportConfig.setWrapText(false);
        xlsxreportConfig.setCollapseRowSpan(true);
        xlsxExporter.setConfiguration(xlsxreportConfig);
        xlsxExporter.exportReport();

        rawBytes = xlsReport.toByteArray();
    }

//The excel file is generated and can be opened if I give filename string as input to SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput 
//which I believe uses file stream internally, but not when using ByteArrayOutputStream as input as used above

    /*JRXlsxExporter xlsexporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
    xlsexporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jp));
    xlsexporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("Somedatareport.xlsx"));
    SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration xlsxreportConfig = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
    xlsxreportConfig.setSheetNames(new String[] { "Some Report" });
    xlsxreportConfig.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
    xlsxreportConfig.setForcePageBreaks(false);
    xlsxreportConfig.setWrapText(false);
    xlsxreportConfig.setCollapseRowSpan(true);
    xlsexporter.setConfiguration(xlsxreportConfig);
    xlsexporter.exportReport();*/
```

Comment: I can't understand why are you trying to do this, what is the purpose?. In any case BASE64Encoder is not an encoder you can use to encode and decode byte arrays. It will ignore all non supported bytes.

Comment: I just want to have the base64 encoded string to be present in the response at the client side. The client side will decode it and get the xml file.

Comment: The xml file?  To me it seems like you are encoding the xlsx file

Comment: oh, sorry, type, the xlsx file I mean.

Comment: @anul is have you resolved it?